# Running automated Powershell-NUnit tests on TeamCity

Tags: c#, powershell, nunit, teamcity

I found this neat way to use NUnit in Powershell. http://elegantcode.com/2009/10/25/integration-test-brought-to-you-by-powershell-nunit-with-a-little-specification-syntax-for-flavoring/
and we are using it many of our tests.

However I want to run these tests in TeamCity. 
I want similar behavior when we use a NUnit runner for running C# tests in TeamCity ie the build fails when the execution of tests fail. Has anyone of you achieved this? I suspect the Powershell runner will just execute it as a simple script, without any indication whether the test passes or fails.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity and http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Build+Failure+Conditions

There is an issue in Powershell runner support http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21554

Comment: You are absolutely right about the Powershell runner issue. We are running it from the cmd line runner and do not seem to be running into that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the approach you're referencing for executing NUnit tests via Powershell in TeamCity. But, we are successfully using [PSake](https://github.com/psake/psake) for Powershell build scripts, including executing NUnit tests and failing the build appropriately. The same issue exists with PSake and TeamCity with exit codes, but you can get around it by specifying in TeamCity in the Script Source for the Build Step using -Command for Script execution:

```
import-module .\tools\psake\psake.psm1
$psake.use_exit_on_error = $true
invoke-psake build.ps1 
remove-module psake
```

You can also integrate the Test results into the TeamCity using the Build Feature option in TeamCity Build Steps.